# Layout Appearing Very Small and Dim

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I used a tutorial to make a GridLayout calculator and it worked out pretty well, but for some reason when I run it in the emulator, it looks faded and it stays in the center rather than filling the screen. The XML that would affect this is as follows:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="#000000"
android:columnCount="4" >
</GridLayout>
```

Here is what the layout looks like in the emulator (Galaxy Nexus emulator on 4.2):

[image: layout issue]

There's a textbox with "3 2 1" at the top of the black box, to illustrate how faded it looks. The buttons are a bright grey in the designer.

Comment: Why don't you use `MATCH_PARENT` for the width and height of the `GridLayout`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it then looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/dwUjAiw.png

Comment: Which is because the + and = buttons have `android:layout_gravity="fill"` added to them, defined for their number of columns/rows. Is there an alternative method for this?